# heroku local fails on my local Ubuntu machine

Tags: php, heroku, apache2, heroku-toolbelt

I'm trying to run my heroku app locally on my ubuntu machine by running `heroku local` as described [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local).

It fails with output:

> [WARN] No ENV file found
>
> 16:58:25 web.1   |  vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2: line 196: php-fpm: command not found
>   16:58:25 web.1   |  This program requires PHP 5.5.11 or newer; check your 'php-fpm' command.
>   16:58:25 web.1   Exited with exit code 1

I uninstalled and re-installed php-fpm (via apt) to make sure I had the newest version, but heroku still complains that php-fpm is not a command.

In trying to debug it, I ran `compgen -c` found that `php-fpm` is not an available command, but `php-fpm7.1` is. Is this just a version issue? I tried to set an alias for it, but it didn't change the result.

Even if the php-fpm check passed, the next check would fail because httpd is also not a command.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Heroku Buildpack for PHP (responsible for the `heroku local`) seems to be incompatible with Ubuntu. There is a request open, some workarounds have been suggested, but so far no real solution has been given:

[Support Debianisms for local execution](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/issues/55)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I contacted Heroku support, and they told me essentially the same thing, that PHP is a special case and heroku local just runs whatever commands are in the Procfile.